# Porting Linux date parsing to FreeBSD

Tags: shell, freebsd, date

I have date in this format: `date -d $datum +"%Y-%m-%d"` and on Linux it worked OK but in FreeBSD says this:

```
ERROR wrong format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[[[cc]yy]mm]dd]HH]MM[.ss]] [+format]
```

what is response to this:

```
date -d $datum +"%Y-%m-%d" >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "ERROR wrong format"
```

But it prints out an error and then continues with the code and it seems that correctly. What am I supposed to do, so it wouldn't print out error and if there is error then the program exits?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434844/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU version of `date` that you're used to on Linux supports a lot more date format than the version of `date` on most other Unix variants. It also has many options that aren't present on other Unix variants. The only [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/date.html) usage of `date` is to display the current date according to a format specified with a `+…` argument (and also a way for the system administrator to set the system date), and the `-u` option to specify UTC instead of the local timezone.

On [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=date&sektion=1), you can use the `date` utility to convert between date formats with the `-f` option, e.g. `date -f %s "$datum" +%Y-%m-%d` to convert a date expressed in seconds from the epoch to a human-readable format.

If you want fancy date parsing, you can install the `coreutils` package, which contains GNU date. Or you can use the [`Date::Parse`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Parse.pm) module in Perl or [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) in Python.

---

To make a shell script stop on most errors, add [`set -e`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-set) just below the `#!` line.

If you want to display an error explicitly, it's up to you to then quit the script with an error status. Print errors to stderr, not to stdout.

```
date -d "$datum" +"%Y-%m-%d" >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
  echo "ERROR wrong format" >&2
  exit 1
}
```

or

```
if ! date -d "$datum" +"%Y-%m-%d" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "ERROR wrong format" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Of course, on FreeBSD one can use the 93 Korn shell, where date manipulation is an extension of the `printf` built-in command.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466487/

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a bsd box to test on, but it appears that you need to use this form:

```
date -f "some format" "$datum" "+%Y-%m-%d"
```

and you have to specify the format of the incoming datum so it can be parsed.

Comment: Shouldn't you also specify option `-j` to prevent `date` from attempting to set the system time?