# Subtract 7 days from today's date

Tags: shell-script, osx, date

Here is my script. I need to subtract 7 days from today's date and use it in a file name. I am using a Mac.

```
#/bin/bash
DATE=$(date -d "-7 days")
echo $DATE
```

When I run this .sh script, I get this:

```
$ /Users/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/dateTest.sh 
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Comment: If you really have smart quotes in your script, that would probably mess things up

Comment: Also, what version of `date` are you using?  That syntax works in `GNU date`, but not `BSD date`

Comment: that looks like it might be OSX

Comment: Just for the record, in linux (GNU date) this works fine.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193088/ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `BSD date` you need a different syntax:

```
DATE="$(date -v-7d)"
```

On my FreeBSD `man date` includes:

```
 -v      Adjust (i.e., take the current date and display the result of the  
         adjustment; not actually set the date) the second, minute, hour,  
         month day, week day, month or year according to val.  If val is  
         preceded with a plus or minus sign, the date is adjusted forwards  
         or backwards according to the remaining string, otherwise the  
         relevant part of the date is set.
```

Comment: $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: DATE=date -v-7d

Comment: I get this error - dateTest.sh: line 2: -v-7d: command not found

Comment: @SkipVV the `bash` version doesn't matter here, it's all about the `date` command itself  If you're saving it in a variable, you still need the `$()` syntax, I'll update my answer for that