# ksh - subtract 5 minutes from current time

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ksh, timestamps

I need to get the date and time of the command `date` minus 5 mins.

```
date:
29 Aug 2018 21:56:01

result:
29 Aug 2018 21:51:02
```

I tried to search on the Internet/forums but most of it involved using the `-d` option and what I have doesn't support the `-d` option.

This one works on Bash but I need something that works on ksh.

```
$ printf "%(%d %h %Y %H:%M:%S)T\n" $(( $(printf "%(%s)T") - 5 * 60 ))
```

Comment: What ksh version do you have? `ksh --version`. And can you also use perl or python?

Comment: `ksh --version` is not working for me. I can use perl.

Comment: chaos is indulging in a little GNU Think.  (-:  The PD Korn shell does not support `--version`.  Neither does the MirBSD Korn shell.  The bigger clue as to whether one is using 93 Korn is the `93` in the name of the command, `ksh93` as it usually is, not `ksh` as chaos said (which is PD Korn on several operating systems, not 93 Korn).

Comment: Why are you demonstrating a 4:59 difference when the title says 5 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `perl`:

```
echo $(( $(printf "%(%s)T") - 5 * 60 )) | perl -lne 'print scalar localtime $_'
```

Or in pure perl:

```
perl -le 'print scalar localtime(time()-5*60)'
```

To format use `strftime()`:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -le 'print strftime("%d %h %Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(time()-5*60))'
```

Comment: The second one works. Thanks! Im not familiar with perl. How can I convert it to match the format above?

Comment: @WaldenSchmidt see my edit

Answer (score 6):

`bash` actually copied the `%(...)T` format from ksh93 but only a small subset.

That's much more powerful in ksh93.

```
$ date; printf '%(%c)T\n' 'exactly five minutes ago'
Mon  3 Sep 08:08:32 BST 2018
Mon Sep  3 08:03:32 2018
```

`bash` only supports Unix epoch times (or `-1` for *now*, though with recent versions you can also get *now* with a missing argument) while ksh93 supports complex relative (including English like above, crontab, `at`, ISO 8601:2004 durations) or absolute time specifications (see the [test data](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/tests/date.dat) in the source for some examples).

In `ksh93`, if you want to pass an epoch time, you use a `#` prefix:

```
$ printf '%(%c)T\n' '#0'
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
```

(though here, [it happens to give the incorrect time for me in a British timezone where epoch time 0 was at 1am](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/17))